# Regular expression for only characters a-z, A-Z

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I don't know how to create a regular expression in JavaScript or jQuery.

I want to create a regular expression that will check if a string contains only characters between a-z and A-Z with any arrangement.

**EDIT**

When I tried to make regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

to accept white spaces as well. It is not working. What could be the mistake?

I am testing my regular expression at *[JavaScript RegExp Example: Online Regular Expression Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)*.

Comment: On your new regex, it should work. It is working here, at least.

Comment: See: http://rubular.com/r/kl8wklKBxy (I know it's ruby, but I tested it on JS as well)

Comment: Your new regex will not work on that site if you included the `/`s, as those delimit the start and end of the expression.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Change the `*` to `+` if you don't want to allow empty matches.

#### References:

[Character classes (`[...]`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors (`^` and `$`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition (`+`, `*`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

The `/` are just delimiters, it denotes the start and the end of the regex. One use of this is now you can use [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) on it.

Comment: why ^ and $ has been used. What is its purpose

Comment: @Shantanu: Those are used to match the beginning and the end of the string. Without them any string containing letters would be matched. Now only strings containing ONLY letters will be matched.

Comment: @Shantanu: ^ is begin of string, $ is end of string. It's used here to make sure the complete string does contain characters. If you would do `/[a-zA-Z]*/` if would also match the string "1234 fo!" (at "fo").

Answer (score 24):

Piggybacking on what the other answers say, since you don't know how to do them at all, here's an example of how you might do it in JavaScript:

```
var charactersOnly = "This contains only characters";
var nonCharacters = "This has _@#*($()*@#$(*@%^_(#@!$ non-characters";

if (charactersOnly.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/) === -1) {
  alert("Only characters");
}

if (nonCharacters.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/)) {
  alert("There are non characters.");
}
```

The `/` starting and ending the regular expression signify that it's a regular expression. The [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) function takes both strings and regexes, so the `/` are necessary to specify a regex.

From [the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#lDescription), the function returns `-1` if there is no match.

Also note: that this works for *only* a-z, A-Z. If there are spaces, it will fail.

Answer (score 13):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Off the top of my head.

Edit:

Or if you don't like the weird looking literal syntax you can do it like this

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Comment: I missed the ^ and $, I'll edit my answer to make it correct but props to @NullUserException for getting it first

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX Bracket Expressions (not supported by Javascript) it can be done this way:

```
/[:alpha:]+/
```

Any alpha character A to Z or a to z.

or

```
/^[[:alpha:]]+$/s
```

to match strictly with spaces.

Comment: But... shouldn't this be /[[:alpha:]]+/ ?

The regular expression [a-zA-Z] will return incorrect values for some character encodings (e.g. EBCDIC, where there is a gap between i and j, and another between r and s (which includes the ~ character), and between I and J and between R and S. This one works everywhere.

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` is correct, but lots of languages will just drop a warning and DWYM. or it might just be untested.

Comment: @James, arguably, if the question is taken literally, `[a-zA-Z]` will give correct results even for EBCDIC, and `[[:alpha:]]` will return incorrect results for EBCDIC. Because the question did not ask for only letters. It asked for a-z, A-Z. :-/

Comment: @LarsH - that's a very (in fact annoyingly) good point, but I think I'll stick with my interpretation. Who really wants to include ~, }, and a bunch of unprintables with a-zA-Z?

Answer (score 2):

This `/[^a-z]/g` solves the problem.

```js
function pangram(str) {
    let regExp = /[^a-z]/g;
    let letters = str.toLowerCase().replace(regExp, '');
    document.getElementById('letters').innerHTML = letters;
}
pangram('GHV 2@# %hfr efg uor7 489(*&^% knt lhtkjj ngnm!@#$%^&*()_');
```

```html
<h4 id="letters"></h4>
```