# How can I determine if a string only contains spaces, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I determine if an input string only contains spaces, using javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532053/regular-expression-for-only-characters-a-z-a-z

Just use search.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another good post for : [Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)

You just need to apply [**`trim`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function and check the length of the string. If the length after trimming is 0 - then the string contains only spaces.

```
var str = "data abc";
if((jQuery.trim( str )).length==0)
  alert("only spaces");
else 
  alert("contains other characters");
```

Comment: Or just `!str.trim()`

Answer (score 9):

```
if (!input.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    //your turn...
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `input` is the value, not the input element.

Comment: Yeah, like `var input="dfdfd"`, I guess, getting input value from real input not a big problem.

Comment: I prefer this solution to .trim(), because you're looking for a specific pattern of characters, and that's precisely and explicitly what a regex describes. It would take a reader a little longer to understand your clever trick with trim.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do a [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) which returns a boolean instead of an array

```
//assuming input is the string to test
if(/^\s*$/.test(input)){
    //has spaces
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!input.match(/^([\s\t\r\n]*)$/)) {
    blah.blah();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is using the regex prototype function [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and looking for any character that is not a space or a line break `\S` :

```
if (/\S/.test(str))
{
    // found something other than a space or a line break
}
```

In case that you have a super long string, it can make a significant difference.