# Input field with spaces only not allow to save in angular?

Tags: html, angular

Here I have one input field when I click on `SAVE` button it goes in `saveNewCategory()` function and check it is null or not, but when I put only spaces in input field that time also it is saved so how it is not allowed to save input field when only spaces is given in the input field?

**category.component.html**

```
<div>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput placeholder="Category Title" maxlength="30" name="categorytitle" [(ngModel)]="this.categoryObj.categorytitle" required>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
  <button mat-raised-button color= "accent" (click)="saveNewCategory()">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

**category.component.ts**

```
saveNewCategory(){
  if(this.categoryObj.categorytitle != ''){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('categorytitle',this.categoryObj.categorytitle);
    this.categoryService.saveNewCategory(formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if(data != undefined && data.status == 1){
          this.snackBar.open('New Category Saved Successfully..!!', '',{
            duration: 2000
          });  
        }
      }
    )
  }else{
    this.snackBar.open('Category Image is required..!!', '',{
      duration: 2000
    });  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine if a string only contains spaces, using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528193/how-can-i-determine-if-a-string-only-contains-spaces-using-javascript)

Comment: @yannick instead of jquery what i have to use here ?

Comment: !this.categoryObj.categorytitle.trim().length == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trim` method as:

```
saveNewCategory(){
  if(this.categoryObj.categorytitle.trim() != ''){ <===== Here
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('categorytitle',this.categoryObj.categorytitle);
    this.categoryService.saveNewCategory(formData).subscribe(
      ...
    )
  }else{
    ...
  }  
}
```