# javascript regex to return letters only

Tags: javascript, regex

My string can be something like A01, B02, C03, possibly AA18 in the future as well.  I thought I could use a regex to get just the letters and work on my regex since I haven't done much with it.  I wrote this function:

```
function rowOffset(sequence) {
              console.log(sequence);
            var matches = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.exec(sequence);
            console.log(matches);
            var letter = matches[0].toUpperCase();
            return letter;
}

var x = "A01";
console.log(rowOffset(x));
```

My `matches` continue to be null.  Am I doing this correctly?  Looking at this post, I thought the regex was correct: [Regular expression for only characters a-z, A-Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532053/regular-expression-for-only-characters-a-z-a-z)

Comment: the linked regex `^[a-zA-Z\s]+$` has a different purpose: It is meant to validate if a String _only_ contains letters (and spaces). You want to _match_ the letters _within_ a String.

Comment: I would like to note that this Q&As are targeting  **only ENGLISH alphabet**, it is not "all letters" but literally just a-z/A-Z ***without*** diacritics/accented letters, it ***won't*** match letters like `é, è, ê, ë, ç, ñ, ø, ð, å, æ, œ, ē, č, ŭ` etc...  :) for that you'd need `/\p{Letter}/gu`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your main issue is the use of the `^` and `$` characters in the regex pattern.  `^` indicates the beginning of the string and `$` indicates the end, so you pattern is looking for a string that is **ONLY** a group of one or more letters, from the beginning to the end of the string.

Additionally, if you want to get each individual instance of the letters, you want to include the "global" indicator (`g`) at the end of your regex pattern:  `/[a-zA-Z]+/g`.  Leaving that out means that it will only find the first instance of the pattern and then stop searching . . . adding it will match all instances.

Those two updates should get you going.

---

**EDIT:**

Also, you may want to use `match()` rather than `exec()`.  If you have a string of multiple values (e.g., `"A01, B02, C03, AA18"`), `match()` will return them all in an array, whereas, `exec()` will only match the first one.  If it is only ever one value, then `exec()` will be fine (and you also wouldn't need the "global" flag).

If you want to use `match()`, you need to change your code order just a bit to:

```
var matches = sequence.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

To return an array of separate letters remove `+`:

```
var matches = sequence.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g);
```

Comment: `/g` doesn't mean "greedy" it means "global":  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags

Comment: @SeanKendle . . . technically, yes.   :)   I think I must have been thinking of how the fflag changes the behavior, back when I answered this ("greedy" seems like a better description of "capturing all instances, instead of just the first one" than "global" does).  I've updated the post for accuracy.

Comment: But, with regex, greedy has a very specific meaning, and `/g` isn't that.

Answer (score 53):

You can use `String#replace` to remove all non letters from input string:

```
var r = 'AA18'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
//=> "AA"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confused about what the goal of the other question was: he wanted to check that there were *only* letters in his string.

You need to remove the anchors `^$`, who match respectively the beginning and end of the string:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

This will match the first of letters in your input string.

If there might be more (ie you want multiple matches in your single string), use

```
sequence.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)
```

Answer (score 3):

This `/[^a-z]/g` solves the problem. Look at the example below.

```js
function pangram(str) {
    let regExp = /[^a-z]/g;
    let letters = str.toLowerCase().replace(regExp, '');
    document.getElementById('letters').innerHTML = letters;
}
pangram('GHV 2@# %hfr efg uor7 489(*&^% knt lhtkjj ngnm!@#$%^&*()_');
```

```html
<h4 id="letters"></h4>
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the cases. Appart of that, it's the same as other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var r = 'AA18'.replace(/[\W\d_]/g, ''); // AA
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can be done by `String.prototype.split(regex)`.

```
'AA12BB34'.split(/(\d+)/);      // ["AA", "12", "BB", "34", ""]
'AA12BB34'.split(/(\d+)/)[0];   // "AA"
```

Here regex divides the giving string by digits `(\d+)`