# only words no numbers or underscores or dashes c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex pattern that accepts words but if the words contains underscore / dashes or number it is not valid so:

```
Word ---> good
Word1.0 ---> no
word_1 ---> no
```

Comment: "I need" is not the question. Please add a bit own work and show what was wrong with your shot.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3532074/6356434)

Comment: @Alex, that thread does not support all words. Only ASCII ones. But this question is very unclear anyway.

Comment: did you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\A[\p{L}\p{M}]+\z
```

In C#:

```
var result = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\A[\p{L}\p{M}]+\z");
```

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of string (replace with `(?![\p{M}\p{L}])` if partial match is required)
- `[\p{L}\p{M}]+` - 1 or more letters or diacritic characters
- `\z` - the very end of the string.