# In javascript using the onkeypress method, I would like to restrict the user from inputting anything non-alphabetical

Tags: javascript, html, onkeypress

I would like to make it so that a function runs only when the user types any key from a-z. Would I need to use a different method other than onkeypress?

Comment: You need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532053/regular-expression-for-only-characters-a-z-a-z

Comment: regexp is overkill, you can check just key codes. As a-z follows each other, you can check if keycode is in range

Comment: so I should store event.keycode into lets say variable x, then check if the value of x is within range?

Comment: Avoid using keycodes. It is being depreciated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode