# Check if a variable contain alphabetic character

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, google-sheets

I am trying to eject every results of an array that contain alphabetic characters. For this, I use :

```
if(gtin.toString().length != 13 || /[a-z\-]+/ig.test(gtin) == true) {
    gtin = "null";
}
```

It's works for some variable… But not every time. For exemple :

- CS230
- C1
- L3940-noir

All of this variables will still appear on the array. Do you have an idea why this doesn't work ? 
Thank you !

Comment: /[a-z \-]+/ try this?

Comment: Can you explain better the results that you want or don't want in the array?

Comment: Can you include the array in your code example?

Comment: (Note that `== true` is never necessary.)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking or what results you expect to see. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532053/regular-expression-for-only-characters-a-z-a-z

Answer (score 1):

You have to add digits and anchor your regex:

```js
var test = [
    'abc',
    'CS230',
    'C1',
    'L3940-noir',
    'ab::cd'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^[a-z0-9-]+$/ig.test(a);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't an answer. It's more an illustration to that it **does** work.

```js
var texts = ['CS230','C1', 'L3940-noir', '1231231231231', '/()!!!###&&&+', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM', '0123456s78901'];

texts.forEach(function(gtin) {
          
  if(gtin.toString().length != 13 || /[a-z\-]+/ig.test(gtin) == true) {
    gtin = "null";
  }
  document.write(gtin + '<br/>');
});
```

Check this snippet  and you'll see that all you're examples are set to null, i.e. "rejected" (which I guess is what you meant). It only lets strings that are 13 characters long, and without letters, through.